# Huggingface Trainer with 2 GPUs doesn't train

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

The Huggingface Forums are kinda dead so I'm trying it here instead.
When I'm training my model with 1 A100 80GB it works fine without any problems. I am using a pretty large model but with PEFT the memory is enough to train on one GPU.

When I try to train the model without PEFT the memory is no longer enough, even with a low batch size and gradient accumulation, i am getting "`CUDA out of memory`". So I added another GPU and thought I could just run the trainer like before, but I'm not getting any return from the `trainer.train()` or any other trainer function.

It just loops endlessly without returning anything.

If it helps, these are my `TrainingArguments()`:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir= "~/{}".format(peft_method),
    logging_dir= "~/logs/{}".format(peft_method),
    learning_rate= 3e-4,
    per_device_train_batch_size= batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size= batch_size,
    num_train_epochs= 10,
    weight_decay= 0.01,
    evaluation_strategy= "epoch",
    save_strategy= "epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end= True,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    optim="adamw_torch",
    save_total_limit = 1
)
```

and my `Trainer()`:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model = model,
    args= training_args,
    train_dataset= processed_data["train"],
    eval_dataset= processed_data["test"],
    tokenizer= tokenizer,
    data_collator= data_collator,
    compute_metrics= compute_metrics,
    callbacks=[callback]
)
```

My device is set to "cuda:0" and the model also gets correctly put on the GPU. I tried to put it on the other GPU as well but it also returned nothing.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using QLORA + PEFT.

Make sure you use **device_map="auto"** when you create your model, transformers trainer will take care of the rest.

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_path,
    use_safetensors=True,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    device_map="auto", )
```

Comment: That solved the initial problem, but now I am getting "RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Expected size 45 but got size 41 for tensor number 1 in the list."

Comment: When preparing your dataset, make sure you are padding them, to have same size of tensors. Something like this: `txt = tokenizer(txt, truncation=True, max_length=max_input_length, padding="max_length")`